# Multiple DataBases using Hibernate in Annotation Style

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, multiple-databases

There have been multiple discussions on this topic in the site but I am using annotations all across to create sessionFactory.

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
```

This is how hibernate.cfg.xml looks like

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">xxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXXX</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <mapping class="XXXX" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- add tomcat datasource instance to springs context -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXDS" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
```

How do I achieve multiple DB integration in this case. One solution that I came across was to create multiple hibernate.cfg.xml and create another session factory for it.

But I have two doubts, 1) How do I indicate in autowiring, which sessionFactory to pick, 2) I will have to duplicate lot of info across hibernate.xml, for example beans. Is there any cleaner approach for this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to / can't use bean injection for the DAOs?  That would solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry but could you please be more specific, provide me some examples, links for this approach. I am getting used to Spring+Hibernate so this is a unique situation for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: @Autowired with @Qualifier("name") will help you to pick which sessionFatory.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactoryName")
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
...
}
```

Second question: you can set hibernate properties: schema and catalog to specify database when working on multiple databases. I have the experience with MS SQL Server, so in entity I added annotation @Table("[database].[schema].[tablename]") and it mapping to the specific table in multiple databases.

Comment: yes this soln works perfectly. Thanks. I added this earlier but somehow the comment was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Posted in reference to comments.

Your Session Factories:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory1" class="...">
    ...
</bean>
<bean id="mySessionFactory2" class="...">
    ...
</bean>
```

Your DAOs:

```
<bean id="myHibernateDao1" abstract="true" p:sessionFactory-ref="mySessionFactory1" />
<bean id="myHibernateDao2" abstract="true" p:sessionFactory-ref="mySessionFactory2" />

<bean id="myObj1Dao" parent="myHibernateDao1" class="..." />
<bean id="myObj2Dao" parent="myHibernateDao1" class="..." />
<bean id="myObj3Dao" parent="myHibernateDao1" class="..." />
<bean id="myObj4Dao" parent="myHibernateDao2" class="..." />
<bean id="myObj5Dao" parent="myHibernateDao2" class="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "component.name" })
@PropertySources(@PropertySource(value = {"file:/file1.properties", "classpath:file2.properties"}))
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean firstSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(firstDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("DRIVER_NAME");
        dataSource.setUrl("DATABASE_URL");
        dataSource.setUsername("DATABASE_USER");
        dataSource.setPassword("DATABASE_PASS");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean secondSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(secondDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("DRIVER_NAME");
        dataSource.setUrl("DATABASE_URL");
        dataSource.setUsername("DATABASE_USER");
        dataSource.setPassword("DATABASE_PASS");
        return dataSource;
    }


    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", SCHEMA_NAME);
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager firstTransactionManager() {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(firstSessionFactory().getObject());
       return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager rdsaTransactionManager() {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(rdsaSessionFactory().getObject());
       return txManager;
    }


}
```